# Removing numbers 8 and 9 from a variable. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c

I'm trying to input two numbers and remove 8s and 9s (not convert them, only remove unneeded numbers) so they can fit in the octal base.

When I run the program and input the numbers, they are almost correctly returned, but they are deducted by a bit.

I still don't know why and how to fix it. It might be something with zeroes, but I don't know.

```
int octal(int a)
{
    int b = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(a > 0){
        if((a % 10) <= 7){
            b= pow(10,i) * (a%10)+b;
            i++;
        }
        a=a/10;
    }
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int j, o, a, b;
    scanf(" %d %d", &j, &o);
    a=octal(j);
    b=octal(o);
    printf("%d\n%d\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

edit: Example

Input: 72349 and 91238
Output: 7233 and 122

Comment: Why don't you read the input as a string, remove all the 8's and 9's from the string, and then use `atoi` to convert it to a number?

Comment: It works fine for me. I enter `983282` it prints `322`.

Comment: I tried entering 983282, but it printed 321. 


You tried it with strings?

Comment: No idea why it's not working for you. Working demo: http://ideone.com/PRlpnd

Comment: Yea.. I don't know either.. But I'm happy the code is good. Ty

Answer (score 0):

Code is encountering a weak `double pow()` that is returning values *near* the expected mathematical result.  When the result is just under a whole number, the conversion back to `int` results in fraction truncation - results appear 1 less then expected.

Could use `round(pow(10,i))` or better yet, stay with `int` math as follows.

Other simplifications possible, but minimal code changes to outline OP's issue.

```
int octal(int a) {
  int b = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int pow10 = 1;
  while (a > 0) {
    if ((a % 10) <= 7) {
      //b = pow(10,i) * (a%10)+b;
      b = pow10 * (a % 10) + b;
      pow10 *= 10;
      i++;
    }
    a = a / 10;
  }
  return b;
}
```

Care for a walk on the recursive side of life?

```
int octal(int a) {
  assert(a >= 0);
  while (a >= 8) {
    int digit = a%10;
    a /= 10;
    if (digit < 8) {
      return octal(a)*10 + digit;
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```